# Get visible text labels in Core Plot

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I need to get the first and last visible text label in my xAxis of the graph. Other than iterating through all the points and verify whether they are in the visible area. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Which labeling policy are you using?

Comment: CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone